# NSUserDefault for a simple game

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm creating a simple game app.
When the user click on the first button and the int click is 0, the he can click on the second button, and so on.
If the user firstly click on the second button and then on the first, his lifes will decreasing.
I'm having problems when the user reaches 0 lifes and the View returns on the first page.
Then when I click on the button to play again, I have 0 lifes and don't 3!

Here is my code:

```
    @implementation livello1

    int click=0;
    int lifes=3;

-(void)updateLifes:(int)lifes{

    if (lifes==1){
        NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"1" forKey:@"UserLifes"];
        [standardDefaults synchronize];
        [self showLifes];
        livello1 *livello1view = [[livello1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        livello1view.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:livello1view animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (lifes==2){
        NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"2" forKey:@"UserLifes"];
        [standardDefaults synchronize];
        [self showLifes];
        livello1 *livello1view = [[livello1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        livello1view.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:livello1view animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (lifes==3){
        NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"3" forKey:@"UserLifes"];
        [standardDefaults synchronize];
        [self showLifes];
        livello1 *livello1view = [[livello1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        livello1view.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:livello1view animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    else if (lifes==0){
        NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        lifes=3;
        [self showLifes];
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"3" forKey:@"UserLifes"];
        [standardDefaults synchronize];
        gioca *giocaview = [[gioca alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        giocaview.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:giocaview animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

-(void)showLifes{
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"Userlifes"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        lifes=1;}
    if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"Userlifes"] isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        lifes=2;}
    if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"Userlifes"] isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        lifes=3;}
    lifesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",lifes];
}

- (IBAction)press1:(UIButton *)button1{
    if ((button1.selected=YES && click==0)){
        click=1;
    }
    else{
        lifes=lifes-1;
        click=0;
[self updateLifes:(lifes)];
}
}

- (IBAction)press2:(UIButton *)button2{
    if ((button2.selected =YES) && click==1){
        click=2;
    }
    else{
        lifes=lifes-1;
        click=0;
        [self updateLifes:(lifes)];    
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidload];
    [self showLifes];
}
```

Comment: don't understand your problem!

Comment: If the user reaches 0 lifes and then wants to play again, the lifes are = 0 instead of 3

Comment: euh... you need to reset your lifes counter.

Comment: where do i need to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another button for "Play Again" and link it to `-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)playAgain` and in that function reset the value of life to 3. And you don't need to pass `lifes` as it is a global variable (though that is not a very good practice). Though I am not really sure about your logic/ implementation for the `click`, you can use the following (slightly optimised) code :

```
@implementation livello1

    int click=0;
    int lifes=3;

-(void)updateLifes{
    if (lifes!=0) {
        NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [standardDefaults setInteger:lifes forKey:@"UserLifes"];
        [standardDefaults synchronize];
        [self showLifes];
        livello1 *livello1view = [[livello1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        livello1view.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:livello1view animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        lifes=3;
        [self showLifes];
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"3" forKey:@"UserLifes"];
        [standardDefaults synchronize];
        gioca *giocaview = [[gioca alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        giocaview.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:giocaview animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

-(void)showLifes{
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    lifesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[standardDefaults integerForKey:@"Userlifes"]];
}

- (IBAction)press1:(UIButton *)button1{
    if ((button1.selected=YES && click==0)){
        click=1;
    }
    else{
        lifes=lifes-1;
        click=0;
        [self updateLifes];
    }
}

- (IBAction)press2:(UIButton *)button2{
    if ((button2.selected =YES) && click==1){
        click=2;
    }
    else{
        lifes=lifes-1;
        click=0;
        [self updateLifes];    
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)playAgain{ //the new function
    lifes = 3;
    click = 0;
    [self updateLifes];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidload];
    [self showLifes];
}
```

Comment: I use click to detect if the user clicks the button in the right order.
Btw, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Well now I have a different problem: when I play the first time, everything goes well.
When i play again, the lifes are 3 but if I click on the button2 instead of the button 1, the View returns the first one, like if I had 0 lifes. (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

on playAgain Button click, setLife counter to 3.